# Replacing Datastore query with variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es, datastore

I am writing a Dialogflow bot where you give it a book or author and the response will have a text excerpt. The data is all stored in Datastore. I have this successfully working with a query specific to a defined book, but I want to write the Datastore query where the input from the user (Book name) is a variable in the query, so I can have one just one query.

I've tried putting the variable in the query string, but it doesn't recognize it as a variable and instead queries the variable, not the value of the variable.

```
const query1 = datastore.createQuery('QuoteTable').filter('Book', '=', 'Harry Potter');

const book = conv.parameters[BOOK_ENTITY].toLowerCase();
 if (book !== null){ 
     return datastore.runQuery(query1).then(results => {
        conv.ask(results[0][0].Quote);
    });
```

What I want is to replace Harry Potter with book. As an example (I know this doesn't work, but it's the idea of it):

```
const query1 = datastore.createQuery('QuoteTable').filter('Book', '=', '$book');
```

Comment: Can you clarify what datastore you're using? What you're trying to do is certainly possible, but it sounds like you're asking for help with querying a particular system, and it is difficult without knowing what system you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following: 
Just a minor adjustment to your original code, to get the variable `book` before setting the `query1`

```
book = conv.parameters[BOOK_ENTITY].toLowerCase();

const query1 = datastore.createQuery('QuoteTable').filter('Book', '=', book);


 if (book !== null){ 
     return datastore.runQuery(query1).then(results => {
        conv.ask(results[0][0].Quote);
    });
```